# How to autofocus on a specific input field in React (after clicking on another element)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I have several input fields in a table (each row has an input field) and each of them are named dynamically like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <input
      key={name}
      type="text"
      value={label}
      name={name}
     />

     <span>Edit</span>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note I am mapping on some object to render each `<td />` that contains an input field.

What I'd like to happen is when I click on "Edit" for that particular row, the input field on the same row will become focused.

What I am seeing from React docs is how to trigger this focus if you have a predefined set of input fields and you're able to do `createRef()` for each field.

But how do you do it if your input fields are dynamically rendered and there could possibly X number of them (depending on the object being mapped)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not dynamically create the `ref` while you map over the object?

```
{elements.map(() => {
  const ref = React.createRef();
  return <td>
    <input
      key={name}
      type="text"
      value={label}
      name={name}
      ref={ref}
    />
    <span onClick={event => {
      ref.current.focus()
    }}>Edit</span>
  </td>
})}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an multiple refs that maps to each item in your table like the example below.

```
  const rows = [
    { id: "a", name: "Panel 1" },
    { id: "b", name: "Panel 2" },
    { id: "c", name: "Panel 3" }
  ];

  const refs = useRef(new Map()).current;
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        {rows.map(row => (
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input
                label={row.name}
                ref={inst =>
                  inst === null ? refs.delete(row.id) : refs.set(row.id, inst)
                }
                type="text"
              />
              <span onClick={() => refs.get(row.id).focus()}>Edit</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
    </div>
```

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-dust-xhu01) to a working sandbox.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the useRef hook. Great tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty array to store your `refs`. Then as you `map` over your data to create your inputs, create and push that `ref` via the `ref` attribute and call-back.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-roentgen-q64jl

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const list = [{ name: "apple", label: "seed" }, { name: "you", label: "cat" }];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.refsArr = [];
  }

  focusIntoInput = index => {
    this.refsArr[index].focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          {list.map(({ name, label }, index) => {
            return (
              <td>
                <input
                  ref={ref => this.refsArr.push(ref)}
                  key={name}
                  type="text"
                  value={label}
                  name={name}
                />
                <span onClick={() => this.focusIntoInput(index)}>Edit</span>
              </td>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In the `focusIntoInput` click-handler, the `index` passed will always correspond to that `ref` in the `refs` array.

Comment: Thanks this answers my question in the context of my current code structure.

Comment: Oops sorry it was causing error if the row doesn't exist yet. @Ahmad solution worked.